# Django-tastypie - how to include choices?

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have a model field like this

```
location_state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
```

Its value is returned by tastypie, but for rendering a listbox a list of all available choices is needed.
What's the best way to expose such choices via a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the [built-in schema](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html?highlight=schema#fetching-data) to inform the client about field options. Still, choice options are not included in the schema resource by default. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611038/in-django-tastypie-can-choices-be-displayed-in-schema) shows one way how to achieve this.

*Edit 2013-03-19*:

Alternatively you could add your choices to the meta field by using / overriding the [`alter_list_data_to_serialize`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#alter-list-data-to-serialize) method in your `ModelResource`.

Comment: That would be one extra ajax request - to get schema. Is it possible to add choices right into "meta" field in json response?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an easy way of getting the choices out for some reason, but this will do the trick.

```
YourModel._meta.get_field('location_state').choices
```

You should note though, `_meta` is an internal implementation detail, but has been relied upon with a large number of apps and extensions so it should be relatively safe to use.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the last bit about exposing via a resource. I've not used tastypie so I can't really comment on that. With django-piston though, you'd just build out a custom resource that included all the required fields (and extras), rather than the `modelform` way of defining which Model the resource should introspect.